# How to serialize the output of a method in Java

Tags: java, serialization, computed-field

My class contains a property "state" that takes values from 0 to 5. When I serialize the object in order to POST it to a webapi I also need to send a boolean flag. The flag's value can be computed by the state value (see code below).

How can I serialize the output of the computeFlag() method? Is it possible in Java? This flag is used only when communicating with the webapi, it's not used anywhere else.

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("State") 
protected int state;

// I want to avoid setting up and storing this flag
//
// @Expose
// @SerializedName("WebApiFlag")
// private boolean flag = false;

// I wanna do this instead, but it doesn't compile
@Expose
@SerializedName("WebApiFlag")
private boolean computeFlag(){
    if (this.state == 0)
        return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Comment: Why? If you can compute it from 'state', so can the server.

Comment: @EJP you're absolutely right, if I can extract the flag based on the value of the 'state' so can the server side. However, the webapi is fixed and I don't have access to it. So, I'm forced to provide a value for this WebApiFlag.